# Knockout value binding with rateLimit and valueUpdate afterkeydown in Firefox is dropping the last typed letter

Tags: knockout.js

I created a JS Fiddle to show the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/evanlarsen/e8bj9upf/7/

When typing in the textbox it should show what you type just below it. This works fine in google chrome browser but when using Firefox the last letter of whatever you type gets dropped.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value: value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
  <div data-bind="text: value"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const App = function(){
    this.value = ko.observable('');
  this.value.extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 800, method: 'notifyWhenChangesStop' } });
}

const app = new App();
ko.applyBindings(app, document.getElementById('app'));
```

How can I get firefox to stop dropping the last letter? I would like to have the observable updated after every keydown but also throttle the update so its not updated on every key press but only after 800 milliseconds of no more key presses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce the issue with Firefox 98.0, but you're better off using the `textInput` binding anyway. It's actually recommended in the [docs](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#note-1-getting-value-updates-instantly-from-inputs).

So:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: value" />
  <div data-bind="text: value"></div>
</div>
```

```
const App = function(){
  this.value = ko.observable('');
  this.value.extend({ rateLimit: 800 });
}

const app = new App();
ko.applyBindings(app, document.getElementById('app'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/xydwpvez/

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'afterkeyup', would this work for your requirement?

This post has a JSFiddle which could help achieve what you want to do with the delay also, utilising rateLimit, at 800 ms;

[Knockout.js delay valueUpdate: afterkeydown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119502/knockout-js-delay-valueupdate-afterkeydown)